# How to display MySQL data with with a PUG file

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, pug

So I have a .pug file called datareview.pug and it is created for this file:

```
app.get('/datareview', function(req, res) {
  db.query("SELECT * FROM events", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.render('datareview.pug');
  });
});
```

As you can see, the app.get function is for /datareview and it gets the specific table data in my database. What I am having trouble with is displaying this table in my /datareview page using the datareview.pug file. Can someone help me in the right direction? Or just give me an example of how a basic table from a MySQL db is displayed using PUG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the express render [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render), it looks like the `render` method accepts a second argument that defines variables for a view.

A simple example using the code provided might look like this:

```js
app.get('/datareview', function(req, res) {
  db.query("SELECT * FROM events", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;

    // Assuming `fields` contains the data you wish to use in your template
    res.render('datareview.pug', { fields });
  });
});
```